# Customizing Search Results Display in Sharepoint Services 3.0 Wiki

Tags: sharepoint, search, metadata, wiki

I'm looking at using a Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 wiki as a metadata repository.  We basically want a community-driven dictionary and for various reasons we're using Sharepoint instead of say MediaWiki.

**What can I do to customize or completely replace searchresults.aspx?**

Features I'd add if I knew how:

1. Automatically load the #1 hit if it is a 100% match to the search term
2. Show the first few lines of each result as a preview so users don't have to click through to bad results
3. Add a "Page doesn't exist, click here to create it" link in cases where there's not a 100% match

I've got Sharepoint Designer installed and it looks like I'll be able to use it to upload any custom .aspx files I create but I don't see that it will give me access to searchresults.aspx.

Note:  Since I plan to access this search tool from an external site via URL parameters it should be fine to leave the existing searchresults.aspx unchanged and  just load this solution as a complementary search option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, everything is possible but you will need to customize it a little bit.

I would recommend you to build a custom web part to display your results. Here is a nice article to start with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms584220.aspx